# read text content in a website for visually impaired people

Tags: web, accessibility

Hello
I've done a Online AddressBook in php+mysql.

I've a specific needs for visually impaired people:

when they choose a contact and press a hotkey combination (or simply a letter) the website **say the telephone number**.

Do you have some suggestion about some solution for it?
A firefox extension? a web-based reader like some kind of captcha i've seen around the web?

Thank you

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution
a web service called Vozme

http://vozme.com/webmasters.php?lang=it

I can easly let it start talk with a accesskey shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Making your website "speak" the number is the wrong way to go about this. You should design your site to be accessible with screen reading software such as [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org) or [Jaws for Windows](http://freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) so visually impaired people can interact with your site in the same way they use all other sites on the web.

Comment: I never say it's public, it's a intranet website for private user